# Purged. `isc-*`. and now get "The system network services are not compatible with this version"

Tags: networking, network-manager

I tried downloading 3 libnl files but it didn't work.

I was trying to set up a dhcp server in my Ubuntu
But i accidently purged.   isc-*. And now I get this error.

Here is my history:

```
  591  sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
  592  cd /etc/
  593  ls
  594  cd dhcp/
  595  sudo subl dhcpd.conf
  596  ifconfig
  597  ls
  598  cd
  599  sudo /etc/dhcp
  600  cd /etc/dhcp
  601  sudo /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart
  602  sudo tail /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
  603  sudo /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart
  604  sudo tail /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
  605  ifconfig
  606  sudo subl dhcpd.conf
  607  ifconfig
  608  sudo subl dhcpd.conf
  609  option netbios-name-servers 192.168.1.1; 
  610  ifconfig
  611  sudo tail /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
  612  sudo apt purge isc-dhcp-server 
  613  sudo service mysql status
  614  q
  615  cd /
  616  sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
  617  sudo subl /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf 
  618  cd /etc/dhcp
  619  cd /
  620  ls /etc/network/interfaces
  621  ls /etc/network/
  622  sudo subl /etc/network/interfaces
  623  ifconfig
  624  sudo systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server.service
  625  cd /etc/dhcp
  626  sudo systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server.service
  627  sudo apt purge isc-*
  628  sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server
  629  cd /
  630  sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server
  631  sudo apt install isc-*
  632  sudo apt install isc-dhcp-common 
  633  sudo apt update
  634  sudo apt upgrade
  635  reboot
  636  sudo service network-manager 
  637  sudo service network-manager  restart 
  638  123
  639  sudo service network-manager  restart 
  640  sudo subl /etc/network/interfaces
  641  history
  642  sudo apt update --fix-missing
  643  sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
  644  sudo service network-manager start
  645  sudo systemctl status  NetworkManager.service 
  646  sudo systemctl start  NetworkManager.service 
  647  sudo systemctl start  network.service 
  648  sudo systemctl start  network-manager.service 
  649  sudo systemctl status   network-manager.service 
  650  sudo systemctl unmask NetworkManager.service 
  651  sudo systemctl start  network-manager.service 
  652  sudo systemctl status   network-manager.service 
  653  sudo service network-manager  restart
  654  sudo service network-manager  status
  655  sudo syst
  656  reboot
  657  sudo dpkg -i libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb 
  658  sudo dpkg -i libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb 
  659  sudo dpkg -i libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb 
  660  reboot
  661  sudo service networking  status
  662  sudo systemctl  status NetworkManager.service 
  663  sudo systemctl  start  NetworkManager.service 
  664  sudo service network-manager  start
  665  sudo dhclinet
  666  lsb_release -a
  667  sudo apt-get update
  668  clear
  669  clear && echo hello
  670  clear && echo heldsasdad
  671  clear && echo 
  672  reboot
  673  sudo dpkg -i l*
  674  reboot
  675  sudo apt-get -reinstall install  network-manager
  676  sudo apt-get --reinstall install  network-manager
  677  ifconfig
  678  sudo apt-get install -f
  679  history
  680  sudo dpkg -i isc-dhcp-server_4.3.5-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
  681  history
  682  sudo subl /etc/network/interfaces
  683  sudo service mysql status
  684  sudo service mysql start
  685  sudo mysql -u root -p
  686  cd /home/noobie/
  687  ls
  688  history>history.txt
```

Comment: You should probably install `isc-dhcp-client` package if it is not installed. If not, and network doesn't work, the package might be still available in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Comment: I couldn't find isc-dhcp-client in /var/cache/apt/archives. Can i download it manually from other devices??

Comment: Downloading should be possible, pages like [xenial](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/isc-dhcp-server), [yakkety](https://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/isc-dhcp-server) or [zesty](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/isc-dhcp-server) should provide links for downloading.

Comment: I did download and install isc-dhcp-client_4.3.5-3ubuntu1_amd64 for zesty which is my ubuntu and rebooted my pc but i still get the same error

Comment: I also started network-manager and networking services after reboot.

Comment: Anyone?????please help. Since this is a such large forum i expected help and probably solution